# Item count isn't showed on parent category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show items count on parent and on child category. So far the count is visible only on child category but when the item is assigned only to parent directory is showing `0`. I have added this in my `Category` model

```
public function addRelation( $categoires )
{

  $categoires->map(function( $item, $key)
  {             
        $sub = $this->selectChild($item->id);
        $item->itemCount = $this->getItemCount($item->id , $item->parent_id );
        return $item = array_add($item, 'subCategory', $sub);
    });
    return $categoires;
}
public function getItemCount( $category_id, $parent_id )
{
    if( $parent_id == 0)
    { // for root-caregory
         $ids = Category::select('id')->where('parent_id', $category_id)->get();
         $array = array();

         foreach ($ids as $id)
         {
            $array[] =  $id->id;
         }
         return Item::whereIn('category_id', $array )->count();
    }
    else
    {
        return Item::where('category_id', $category_id)->count();
    }
}
```

In the controller

```
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getCategories();
    return view('home', compact('allCategories'));
```

And in my blade

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">{!!$category->title!!} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">({!! $category->itemCount !!})</span></h4>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

`itemCount` is (0) when item is in `Parent` category.

Comment: There is a problem in your logic !! there is no case where the else bloc will be executed always just the first bloc that will be executed !!

Comment: One more thing you can convert the collection `$ids` to array like this `$ids->toArray()` witout looping over its items ;) and did you figured out what you should do ??

Comment: @Maraboc, else block is executed. Inside the foreach I have another foreach which take child categories. It is working as it must as I stated in question that's why I removed it from the question. And no, I didn't figured it out how to show count of items in main category.

Comment: Also I think the counter should count All items from all childs.

Comment: ok assume that you have cat(id=1, parent_id=0) this cat has an item related directly with it whitch bloc will be executed if or else?

Comment: I want you to figure it out just that you can solve the same problems later ;) that's all :)

Comment: `cat(id=1, parent_id=0)` this will trigger the block `IF` because the item is assigned to parent. All parents are presented as `0` in DB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156088/discussion-between-maraboc-and-peter).

Comment: Are you there @Peter let us continue the discussion !!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @Jonjie no, just showing `Category(0)`

Comment: @Peter do you have `itemCount` field in your database?

Comment: @Jonjie, no I don't. I've added to question what I have also in the model for itemCount

Comment: @Peter Then where are you trying to get `itemCount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Discution that we had it's a simlpe query that you want just do it like this :

```
public function getItemCount( $category_id)
{
    return Item::where('category_id', $category_id)->count();
}
```

Or if you have a relationship you can simply do it like this :

```
public function addRelation( $categoires )
{

  $categoires->map(function( $item, $key)
  {             
        $sub = $this->selectChild($item->id);
        $item->itemCount = $item->items()->count();
        return $item = array_add($item, 'subCategory', $sub);
    });
    return $categoires;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again!

Comment: @Peter see the conversation !

Comment: @Peter is the problem [Selecting and check if user exist in table without foreach in laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951352/selecting-and-check-if-user-exist-in-table-without-foreach-in-laravel-blade) still remains ?

Comment: yes. When I have two products in order and leave review for both of them this happen -> button "Leave Review" is shown on both. like on image which I'm attached to the question.

Comment: @Peter Can we discuss on [chating](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157974/peter-problem)

Comment: Yes, we can. I'm in the chat room