# Selecting and check if user exist in table without foreach in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't figured it out how can I make following. User can see details of his order. I want to make button for a user to be able to leave a review of the product which he purchased.

When he left review for a product I want to change the button from "submit review" to "edit review". Problem is how to do this if he purchased 2 or more items? I want to be able to leave review for each item separately.

In the controller I have this function:

```
public function orderView($orderId)
{
    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->first();
    $reviews = Review::where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->first();

    return View::make('site.users.orders_view', [
        'order' => $order,
        'reviews' => $reviews
    ]);
}
```

So, here I select his orders and reviews for authenticated user. Where I show button on the view "submit review", "edit review" I've tried this

```
@forelse($reviews as $review)                           
    @if($review->product_id == $item->product_id)                               
        @if($review->rating_published == 0)
            <a>Waiting</a>
        @else
            <a href="">Edit</a> 
        @endif  
    @else
        <a href="">Add</a>
    @endif
@empty                              
    <a href="">Add</a>
@endforelse
```

If user has 2 products in that order and left only for one of them review both buttons are changed to `Edit Review`.

What I want to do is if user has 2 products in that order and review for 1 of the products to have one button "edit review" and one "submit review"

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use foreach?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi because I get each button twice with foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the relationships in the Product model and Review model you can edit the Controller code as follow :

```
public function orderView($orderId)
{
    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->where('status', 1)
                    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)
                    ->first();

    $productIds = $order->getOrderProductIds();
    $reviews = Review::with('item')
                        ->whereHas('item', function($q) use($productIds){
                            $q->whereIn('product_id', $productIds);
                        })
                        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)
                        ->get();

    return View::make('site.users.orders_view', [
                                                'order' => $order,
                                                'reviews' => $reviews
                                                ]);
}
```

Then add this hepler method in the Product model :

```
public static function hasReview($reviews, $product_id)
{
    foreach ($reviews as $review) {
        if ($review->item->product_id == $product_id) {
            return $review;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And in the view you should do this :

```
<?php $review = \App\Product::hasReview($reviews, $item->product_id)?>
@if($review != null)
    @if($review->rating_published == 0)
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Waiting for Approval ID: {{$item->product_id }}</a>
    @else
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ URL::to('/users/review/' . $item->product_id . '?_token=' . csrf_token()) }}">Edit Review ID: {{$item->product_id }}</a>
    @endif
@else
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ URL::to('/users/review/' . $item->product_id . '?_token=' . csrf_token()) }}">Leave Review ID: {{$item->product_id }}</a>
@endif
```

PS : Think of adding :

- Many to Many relationship between Product and Order => it will helps you in many things especially queries.
- Helper class witch will contains the helper methods like `hasReview`

Answer (score 1):

You can make something better, with retrieving order's reviews.

So in your model Product, you make:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review'); //depends from namespace of your model Review
}
```

And in your model Review:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product'); //depends from namespace of your model Product
}
```

And after in your controller:

```
public function orderView($orderId)
{
    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->first();
    return View::make('site.users.orders_view', [
        'order' => $order
    ]);
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@foreach($order->product->reviews as $review)
    @if($review->user_id == Auth::user()->user_id)
       <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="">Edit Review</a></li>
    @else
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="">Submit Review</a></li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157573/discussion-on-answer-by-moslem-cherif-selecting-and-check-if-user-exist-in-table). Please update the answer with additional information/clarification.